# Replace a string in text file with just fprintf and fscanf

Tags: c, scanf, printf

Sorry for such easy question, this is part of my assignment and I'm stuck. As you can see

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){


FILE *menu;
FILE *update;
FILE *updatewrite;  
menu = fopen("menu.txt","w");

char selection,name[10],updateid,dump ; 
int mealnum,i,j,id,price ;

start:  

scanf("%c%c",&selection,&dump); 


if (selection =='r'){

printf ("Enter the number of meals to be entered\n");
scanf("%d",&mealnum);   

    for(i=0;i<mealnum;i++){
        printf("Enter the name of me1al\n");
        scanf("%s",&name);
        printf("Enter the ID of meal\n");   
        scanf("%d",&id);
        printf("Enter the Price of meal\n");
        scanf("%d",&price);
        fprintf(menu,"%s %d %d\n",name,id,price);
        }
        fclose(menu);
        }


else if(selection =='u'){


update = fopen("menu.txt","r");

int count=0;
while(fscanf(update,"%s %d %d\n",name,&mealnum,&price) != EOF){
printf("Update %s %d %d?\n Y to update any other key for next",name,mealnum,price);
scanf("%c",updateid);
count++;
break;  
}

printf("Enter the new name of meal\n");
scanf("%s",name);
printf("Enter the new ID of meal\n");   
scanf("%d",&id);
printf("Enter the new Price of meal\n");
scanf("%d",&price);


fclose(update);

updatewrite = fopen("/home/mbp/menu.txt","w+"); 

for(j=0;j<count;j++){fscanf(updatewrite,"%s %d %d\n",name,mealnum,price);} //trying to move buffer to proper overwriting location by looping one less times

fprintf(updatewrite,"%s %d %d\n",name,mealnum,price);


fclose(updatewrite);}


else if(selection =='d'){}
else if(selection =='s'){}
else if(selection =='b'){}
else if(selection =='q'){
    return 0;
}
else{printf ("Not VALID!");}
goto start;


return 0; }
```

Nothing other than fscanf, fprintf is accepted.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: full code updated, assigment changed, single file needs to replaced, I'm not allowed use a second file.

Comment: could you paste the whole function? becasue this doesn't really makes any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have two files, open both files at the same time. As you read each line from one, you either write the same data to the other, or new data to the other, depending on the user's choice.

```
FILE *update = fopen("menu2.txt", "r");
FILE *menu = fopen("/home/mbp/menu.txt","w+");

for (...) {
    fscanf(update, ...);
    if (user_wants_update()) {
        get_new_info(...);
        fprintf(menu, ...); /* print the new info */
    } else {
        fprintf(menu, ...); /* print the old info */
    }
}

fclose(menu);
fclose(update);
```

Comment: Thanks you for information, but now it needs to just one file which is being read and written

Comment: The most straight forward solution would be to read the whole file into memory, and then write out the modified file after all the changes are done to the in memory copy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of "it does not works" would benefit with more detail as in *how* odes it not work.  Here is my best shot.

**Change "%c" to " %c"**

The OP code mixes `scanf("%s",...` with `scanf("%c",...`.  This is a problem if before the  `scanf("%c",...`, somewhere in unposted code, you performed a `scanf("%s",...` or the like.

The `scanf("%s",buf)` consumes all leading white space and then puts the following non-white text in `buf`, *leaving* the "enter" (`\n`) in the input buffer.  A following `scanf("%c",...` will then read the (`\n`) and not even wait fro you to type something like `y`.  By changing "%c" to " %c", that (`\n`) and additional white space will get consumed (and tossed) and *then* your `y` will get scanned.

Further, consider checking the return value of scanf() and fscanf().  It will certianly help you debug your code.

Comment: Thanks for the great catch, I didn't know that. Yet sadly still more issues to fix. Does " " matches "\n" or I need to "\n" for them?

Comment: In `scanf()`, ` ` scans 0 or more white-spaces.  `\n` scans 0 or more white-spaces.  White space scans 0 or more white-spaces.  To scan explicitly a `\n`, use `%[\n]`.  Use `%*[\n]` if you do not want to save the result to a `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do more than scan and print. here is some pseudo code for you:

```
read in line from file 1
check if line needs modification
if so
    modify line
write line to file 2
```

Here is a simple example program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f1 = fopen("1.txt", "r");
    FILE *f2 = fopen("2.txt", "w");
    char line[50];

    while (fscanf(f1, "%s", line) != EOF)
    {
        if (strcmp(line, "replaceme") == 0)
        {
            strcpy(line, "replaced");
        }
        fprintf(f2, "%s", line);
    }
    fflush(f2);
    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
}
```

Comment: That is the challenge, doing it just with fscanf fprintf

Answer (score 0):

May be this can work. I fixed two mistake about you code .

```
update = fopen("menu2.txt","r");// you open a FILE and give the fileid to updata

for(j=0;j<kk;j++) {
    fscanf(update,"%s %d %d\n",name,&mealnum,&price);
    //so you have a file ,already writed format things. 
    printf("Update %s %d %d?\n Y to update any other key for next",name,mealnum,price);
    scanf("%c\n",&updateid); 
    //I think it's better use "%c\n", then you can know it not stay in buffer.  
    if(updateid == 'Y') //as we print, 'Y' to update .. 
        break;//          if you can not use goto , don't use.//goto out;   
}
//out:
// I believe you already declare all those values.
printf("Enter the name of meal\n");
scanf("%s",&name);
printf("Enter the ID of meal\n");   
scanf("%d",&id);
printf("Enter the Price of meal\n");
scanf("%d",&price);

fclose(update);// close the (FILE * ) update. In fact, I think here is you mistake.

menu = fopen("/home/mbp/menu.txt","w+");//menu is used just now.    

for(d=0;d<j-1;d++) {
   // fscanf(menu,"%s %d %d\n",name,mealnum,price);
   //here ,you overwrite you values. All you input is missing; Here is another mistake.
    int mealnum1,price1;
    char name1[10];//I don't know the size...  :)
      fscanf(menu, %s %d %d\n",&name1,&mealnum1,&price1);
}

fprintf(menu,"%s %d %d\n",name,mealnum,price);
```