# Any way to replace a string of the exact length in a binary in C

Tags: c, string, replace, binary, segmentation-fault

I have been working on a fairly large program and have run into an issue. I am trying to replace a certain string in a binary with [another method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028324/replace-a-string-in-text-file-with-just-fprintf-and-fscanf) I found on this site. But, I get a "Segmentation fault: 11" when attempting to execute it. I just need a way to replace a string in a binary with another string. I have experimented with other methods but some just corrupt the entire binary when they old one and the new one are compared side by side. Here is my current function code that does not work:

```
int addBootArgs(char* bootArgs,char* iBECorig) {
  char* defaultArgs = "rd=md0 nand-enable-reformat=1 -progress";
  if (strlen(bootArgs) > strlen(defaultArgs)) {
    printf("Too many boot-args for iBEC to handle. It can only take %lu characters.\n",strlen(defaultArgs));
  exit(0);
  }
  if (strlen(bootArgs) < strlen(defaultArgs)) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 39; i++) {
      if (strlen(bootArgs) < strlen(defaultArgs)) {
        bootArgs = addVars(bootArgs," ");
      }
    }
  }
  printf("default-args =[%s]\n",defaultArgs);
  printf("userboot-args=[%s]\n",bootArgs);
  printf("Boot args length is %lu\n",strlen(bootArgs));
  FILE* iBECin = fopen(iBECorig,"rb");
  char* lastiBEC = addVars(tmpdir,"pwnediBEC");
  FILE* iBECout = fopen(lastiBEC,"wb");
  char line[50];
  while (fscanf(iBECin, "%s", line) != EOF) {
    if (strcmp(line, defaultArgs) == 0) {
      strcpy(line, bootArgs);
    }
    fprintf(iBECout, "%s", line);
  }
  fflush(iBECout);
  fclose(iBECin);
  fclose(iBECout);
  return -1;
}
```

Also, the function `addVars();` is just a little something I have to combine two strings quickly, nothing really important if the question came up as to why that wasn't a vanilla C function. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't think reading binary file with `%s` format of `fscanf()` and writing binary file with `%s` format of `fprintf()` is good idea. Conssider using `fread()` or `getc()` for reading, and `fwrite()` or `putc()` for writing.

Comment: `char line[50]; while (fscanf(iBECin, "%s", line) != EOF) {` is a problem when 50+ `char` are read into `line`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>   char line[50];
>   while (fscanf(iBECin, "%s", line) != EOF) {
>     if (strcmp(line, defaultArgs) == 0) {
>       strcpy(line, bootArgs);
>     }
>     fprintf(iBECout, "%s", line);
>   }
> ```

You can't `scanf` binary data into a string for several reasons:

- your binary data is **not null-terminated**, so `fscanf` will keep on scanning.
- your buffer is fixed at 50 bytes, so it will **overflow**.

What you need is `fread()` and `fwrite()`.

Assuming that all the `records` in your files are 39 bytes, you could do as follows in your loop:

- `fread()` 39 bytes in buffer.
- `memcmp()` with `defaultArgs`.
- depending on the outcome, `fwrite()` `----Args` to `iBECout`.

Comment: Okay, I managed to fix it with fread() and fwrite() and it is just copying my file now. It doesn't seem to understand that it has found the correct line with `memcmp()`. Here is my implemintation: `memcmp(defaultArgs,buf,sizeof(buf)`. Does this seem to be correct? It doesn't seem to be working for me, but I get no errors, so that means some progress.

Comment: @dayt0n - I guess with `buf` you mean `line` in your original code. `sizeof(buf)` will be 50, while your records are 39 bytes, so you probably need `memcmp(defaultArgs,buf,39)`. It's also better to put that 39 in a variable or #define. You also need to check the loop around `addVars()`.

Comment: Sorry, I made a few changes. Here is the revised version: https://ghostbin.com/paste/yjz6v (There wasn't enough room to paste in the entire function in a comment).

Comment: @dayt0n - In `fread()` and `fwrite()`, you have your 2nd and 3rd parameters mixed up. Should be the other way around.

Comment: @dayt0n - Also: if your buffers are not null-terminated, don't use `strcpy()`. Just use `fwrite()` in both cases with an `if-statement`.

Comment: I did what you said and I am still having one tiny issue (thanks for the help so far, though): memcmp doesn't seem to find the string. Could it be that since it is reading everything in segments of 39 bytes, it could be cutting off part of the string? Here are the changes I made if you need those: https://ghostbin.com/paste/8ocz5

Comment: I was assuming that all your records were fixed at 39 bytes (since you seem to pad them, and you want to access your data in binary mode). If that is not the case, you will have to do some redesign. You could try to check your buffers in the debugger before `memcmp()`