# If a word has been found then how to replace it in another file?

Tags: c, replace, updates

I have this code which I divided in two parts just for understanding purpose. The first option is working fine and showing me details to update.

I have a problem with the second part in which a code is taking **name/word** from the file correctly but I don't know how to replace it with the new **name/word** in another file? Could you help me with some code because I searched a lot? Thanks!

**Here is file.txt**

```
bilalkhan 20/20/1980 908732343
```

**Here is a code**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void firstWord(char str[]){
    int i = 0;
    while(!isspace(str[i])){
      i++;
    }
    str[i]='\0';
}

void hello(){
    int option;
    char updated_name[50], read[100];
    short int FLAG = 0;
    
    static const char * listing[] = {"Name", "Date of birth","ID card number"};
    
    FILE * fr3 = fopen("file.txt","r");
    FILE * fw1 = fopen("new.txt","w");
    
    if (fr3 == NULL || fw1 == NULL) {
        perror("Unable to read text file.");
        exit(0);
    }

    for (option = 1; option <= sizeof(listing)/sizeof(char *); ++option)
       printf("%d. Your %s\n", option, listing[option-1]);
```

**SELECT OPTION TO UPDATE**

```
    fputs("Select your choice to update: ", stdout);
    scanf("%d", &option);

    char string[100];
    if (option == 1){
        while(fgets(string, 100, fr3) != NULL){
            firstWord(string);
            printf("'%s' found. Now replace it with another name: ", string);
            scanf("%s", &updated_name);
                 // Here I want to update the name but don't know the code.
            fclose(fr3);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    fclose(fw1);
}
int main(){  hello(); }
```

Comment: What does `firstWord()` do? You need to extract all the fields from the file. Then print the updated name followed by the other fields to the output file.

Comment: `firstword()` takes the first word file.txt. I just used to show that in result that `firstword()` is found. I search a lot to extract and replace didn't find the understable answer.

Comment: Where does it put the word? It looks like it's replacing `string` with the first word. How can you get the second and third word after that?

Comment: Right now I am just working on first word.

Comment: But you need to get all the words so you can print them to the output file. You want to print `updated_name` followed by the second and third words.

Comment: BTW, your `firstword()` function looks like `strtok(string, " ")`

Comment: `firstword()` extracts the first word from the file and then print this but the point you are talking about I am not understanding. Will you please show me with code?

Comment: I assume you want to write `newname 20/20/1980 908732343` to the output file. You can't do that if you've discarded the 2nd and 3rd words.

Comment: I just want to write newname in another file. This is a just a file text in which I wrote name, dob and phone number so that I could replace newname and put in new.txt

Comment: Then what's the problem? `fprintf(fw1, "%s\n", updated_name)`

Comment: `printf("'%s' found. Now replace it with another name: ", string);` Here when I will write the name then the newname should be written in new.txt. But I don't know how to transfer that newname in new.txt and replace it with oldname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write the updated name to the output file.

```
    if (option == 1){
        while(fgets(string, 100, fr3) != NULL){
            firstWord(string);
            printf("'%s' found. Now replace it with another name: ", string);
            scanf("%s", &updated_name);
            fprintf(fw1, "%s\n", updated_name);
            fclose(fr3);
            fclose(fw1);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    fclose(fw1);
```

You're not really replacing anything, you're just asking for a new name and putting it into the file. The old name is not used in this process.

Comment: But I have a question Barmar. My new.txt contains name 20/20/1980 908732343. When I try to replace the name with newname from file.txt all the text in new.txt delete. I just want to replace my name from new.txt file and the else text should remain there and the same.

Comment: You can't replace directly in a file. You have to read the old contents into variables, update the parts you want, then write that back out to the file.

Comment: You can only overwrite directly if the replacement is the same length as the original. But since names can be different lengths, that won't work.

Comment: So I read from file by using firstword. Is there another way to update that old text with new text in another file?

Comment: okay then take dob or phone number which are of same length

Comment: The problem is that the name is not the same length. You can't overwrite it with a different length.

Comment: If the file is originally `bilalkhan 20/20/1980 908732343` and the new name is `joe`, when you overwrite the name you'll get `joealkhan 20/20/1980 908732343` because there's no way to shift the rest of it over. You have to read it all in to separate variables, then write out the modified variables.

Comment: Okay, then what about DOB or phone number which are of same length? Does this require also separate variables?

Comment: You need a variable to hold them so you can write them out after the name. Whether they're the same or different length is irrelevant. I think you don't really understand the basic principles.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028324/replace-a-string-in-text-file-with-just-fprintf-and-fscanf for some examples.

Comment: Thank you Barmar for guiding me. I am actually started now learning C. So I need to do a lot of hard work.